# Rest API ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have created an MVC project (Say DeploymentTool) and added another webAPI project to the solution (Say DeploymentToolAPI), and hence NameSpace is different for both. Now what I want is, to call any HTTPPOST/ HTTPGET method of DeploymentToolAPI from outside, say POSTMAN or web browser. Do we need to update WebApiConfig.cs for that? 
If not, how can I find the URL of DeploymentToolAPI. I am able to call any method of DeploymentTool but it's not working in case of DeploymentToolAPI.

Would appreciate any help/ suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to [Set Multiple Startup Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx) to make both your API service and the MVC web application start up simultaneously:

In Visual Studio right click your solution -> Properties -> Select "Multiple startup projects:" -> set the *Action* of both projects to Start:

[image: Set Multiple Startup Projects in Visual Studio]

Once this is done follow the instructions posted by @Ankush Jain or just copy the WEB API url from the browser window, because when you run the project after setting multiple startup projects you will see that both your web api service and the MVC web application will be opened in the browser in two different tabs.

Comment: Yeah got that. Thanks Denis.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on your WEB API project and go to Properties
2. Go on Web tab and you will see project URL textbox
3. This will tell you the base url for your web api project. (ie. http://localhost:8526)
4. Then go to WebApiConfig.cs to check URL route pattern.

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web.Http;

   namespace StandardWebApiTemplateProject
   {
       public static class WebApiConfig
       {
           public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
           {
               config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                   name: "DefaultApi",
                   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
               );
           }
       }
   }
   ```

If you have Route Template like -

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}" then your url will be like 
ie. http://localhost:8526/api/ControllerName/89
```

and if you include action name in route template then case will be like below

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}" then your url will be like 
ie. http://localhost:8526/api/ControllerName/ActionName/89
```

Comment: Thanks Ankush. You explanation #2 gave me what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.